# Why ASP.NET Core project has dependency constraint to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have the following warning:

> Warning   NU1608  Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic 4.4.0 requires Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.4.0) but version Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.8.0-3.final was resolved.

There's no **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic** or **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common** in my Nuget Packages.

While adding the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" Version="4.8.0-3.final" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="4.8.0-3.final" />
```

will resolve the problem but still I don't underestand it... Why my (C#) ASP project need a VisualBasic package in itself?

---

EDIT:

for more information, my project has 5 layer Onion Architecture. the Project csproj has this implementation:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</UserSecretsId>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="NPOI" Version="2.6.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="KavenegarDotNetCore" Version="1.0.7" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="8.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client" Version="8.0.2">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="PersianDateTime.Core" Version="2.0.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.3.7" />

    <PackageReference Include="Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore" Version="2024.1.2" />

    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.Pdf" Version="24.1.43" />

    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WebFrameWork\WebFramework.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\js\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  
</Project>
```

other csproj file in the topper layer (putting together) has these packages:

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Pluralize.NET" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="PersianDateTime.Core" Version="2.0.5" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.2" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>

<PackageReference Include="KavenegarDotNetCore" Version="1.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
```

Comment: Can you please share full csproj file? Maybe one of the packages used requires them as dependency?

Comment: @GuruStron Ok. I added it to the question body.